# Extract the time stamp from kafka messages in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

Trying to read from kafka source. I want to extract timestamp from message received to do structured spark streaming.
kafka(version 0.10.0.0)
spark streaming(version 2.0.1)

Comment: Could you show a snippet of your current code?

Comment: @vanekjar val ds1 = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "topicA")
  .load()

Answer (score 3):

```
spark.read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "your.server.com:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "your-topic")
  .load()
  .select($"timestamp", $"value")
```

Field "timestamp" is what you are looking for. Type - java.sql.Timestamp. Make sure that you are connecting to 0.10 Kafka server. There is no timestamp in earlier versions.
Full list of fields described here - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest couple things:

1. Suppose you create a stream via latest [Kafka Streaming Api (0.10 Kafka)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)

   E.g. you use dependency: `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % 2.0.1`

   Than you create a stream, according to the docs above:

   ```
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
        "bootstrap.servers" -> "broker1:9092,broker2:9092",
        "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        "value.deserializer" -> classOf[ByteArrayDeserializer],
        "group.id" -> "spark-streaming-test",
        "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
        "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean))

   val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
   // suppose you have 60 second window
   val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(60))
   ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

   val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, PreferConsistent,
   Subscribe[String, Array[Byte]](topics, kafkaParams))
   ```
2. Your stream will be an DStream of [ConsumerRecord[String,Array[Byte]]](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) and you can get a timestamp and key-value as simple as:

   ```
   stream.map { record => (record.timestamp(), record.key(), record.value())  }
   ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do you convert the above stream.map { record => (record.timestamp(), record.key(), record.value())    to DF. am new to spark i want to onclude timestamp from kafka also while converting to DF. can you please tell me how to do it

Comment: @BigD You could do something like: 
    stream.foreachRDD{  (rdd: RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, Array[Byte]]], time: 
   Time) =>
       rdd.map(//some mapping).toDF      
 }

Comment: if i do rdd.map(//some mapping).toDF i am converting my values part to DF.. i want to include timestamp also while converting to DF