# Order of messages with Spark Executors

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming application which streams data from kafka. I rely heavily on the order of the messages and hence just have one partition created in the kafka topic.

I am deploying this job in a cluster mode.

My question is: Since I am executing this in the cluster mode, I can have more than one executor pick up tasks and will I lose the order of messages received from kafka in that case. If not, how does spark guarantee order?

Comment: you would have to write your own to achieve ordering. do you have any timestamp as a part of message?

Answer (score 1):

The distributed processing power wouldn't be there with single partition, so instead use multiple partitions and I would suggest to attach sequence number with every message, either counter or timestamp.
If you don't have timestamp within message then kafka streaming provide a way to extract message timestamp and you can use it to order events based on timestamp then run events based on sequence.

Refer answer on [how to extract timestamp from kafka message.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586663/extract-the-time-stamp-from-kafka-messages-in-spark-streaming)

Answer (score 0):

To maintain order using single partition is the right choice, here are few other things you can try:

1. Turn off speculative execution

> spark.speculation - If set to "true", performs speculative execution
>   of tasks. This means if one or more tasks are running slowly in a
>   stage, they will be re-launched.

2. Adjust your batch interval / sizes such that they can finish processing without any lag.

Cheers !